# Query PFObject with full PFUser info

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im my object "car" i have a column called "owner" in which i save the PFUser object to.  When I query this "car" object and try to get the owner's name, I have to call `owner.fetchIfNeeded()` in order to get the PFUser's custom columns such as "firstname".  How can my original query make sure to include all extra columns on PFUsers so I do not have to call `fetchIfNeeded()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the includeKey method to fetch the PFUser object with the original query.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"car"];
[query includeKey:@"owner"];
```

You can also use multi-level includes using dot notation to retrieve relational data on the user object. e.g.

```
[query includeKey:@"owner.profilePicture"];
```

References:

- https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/includeKey:
- https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS